# remove first result in foreach looop in C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I have following foreach loop , I want to skip first result and and get rest of it

```
    foreach (String W in words)
    {
     ...
    }
```

How can I do this

Comment: Do a `for(int = 1..` ?

Comment: cant I do with `foreach` ?

Comment: if you're using linq: `words.Except(words.First())`?

Comment: @garglblarg: ahem, i don't think that OP wants to skip all which are equal to the first, but even then your syntax is incorect. This would be better: `words.Where(w => w != words.First())`

Comment: @TimSchmelter oh right, `Except` needs something enumerable as an argument and concerning the removal of identical elements: true, i was just assuming a collection of unique elements.

Answer (score 3):

Simple use `Skip` extension method (using LINQ) like this:

```
   foreach (String W in words.Skip(1))
        {
         ...
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bit of LINQ to [`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) items from the front of an `IEnumerable<T>`

```
foreach (String W in words.Skip(1))
{
 ...
}
```